# Excel, como extrair dados de uma coluna com duas variáveis relacionando essas variáveis com outras duas variáveis

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Tabela a ser organizada]

A minha idéia aqui, seria colocar a QTD da CA1 na hora de 14:49 na coluna B 2x2, e assim por diante, organizando todos os horários.

[image: Aqui é um exemplo de uma planilha ajustada]

Comment: olá Celso, o que já tentou fazer? coloque na pergunta a formula que já usou e qual a dificuldade ou que não deu certo

Answer (score 0):

É possível realizar essa ação com a fórmula `=somases`, ela retorna o somatório de um intervalo/coluna com base em condições (Hora e Tipo, nesse caso). Ficaria assim na célula B2:

```
=SOMASES($P:$P;$N:$N;$A2;$O:$O;B$1)
```

A chave está em utilizar corretamente a referência relativa e absoluta, que é o cifrão ($) na fórmula, [veja](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/alternar-entre-refer%C3%AAncias-relativas-absolutas-e-mistas-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9).

No código acima, as colunas P, N e O estão definidas como absolutas, ou seja, ficam fixas ao inserir a fórmula em qualquer coluna que terá o resultado (intervalo de B2:I34, por exemplo)). Utilizamos o $ na frente de todo o intervalo.

Já as referências de critérios, misturam relativo e absoluto. A `$A2` deixa a coluna absoluta (fixa) e a linha relativa (variável), enquanto o `B$1` faz o contrário, deixa a coluna relativa e a linha absoluta. Utilizamos o $ somente na parte específica.